# call struts2 action through html action

Tags: html, struts2

Hi every one.I want code for how to call a struts2 action file from normal HTML action tag. Is it possible to call? can any one explain me. thanks

Comment: Could you tried something ? if yes  Please post the code you tried.

Comment: I suppose you mean an HMTL form tag with an action attribute?  Yes, it's possible.  JSPs, after all, are sent to the client as regular HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible because all struts2 tags will be converted into normal html tag at the time of submitting form.So you can submit normal html also for Struts2.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="Login">
// your stuff goes here for input
</form>
```

**Struts XML :**

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
<action name="Login" class="packagename.actionclassname">
<result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: @David Karki please try something before ask.Thank you.